# unable to map abi string to array to object with known keys source, contract

Tags: polkadot-js, smart-contract, kusama

I am trying to use the `ContractPromise` from `@polkadot/api-contract` to interact with a published smart contract on the moonriver network but when I try and create a new `ContractPromise` object I get the error

```
Error: createType(ContractProjectInfo):: Struct: Unable to map" + abi string + "array to object with known keys source, contract"
```

I'm not entirely sure why this is because the ABI and contract address seem to be correct.

The code I am using to test it out is here:

```js
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from "@polkadot/api";
import { ContractPromise } from "@polkadot/api-contract";
import { ksmContractABI } from "./consts";

async function main() {
  console.log("start");
  const ksmContractAddress = "0xFfc7780C34B450d917d557E728f033033CB4fA8C";
  const wsProvider = new WsProvider("wss://kusama-rpc.polkadot.io");
  const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });
  const contract = new ContractPromise(
    api,
    JSON.stringify(ksmContractABI),
    ksmContractAddress
  );
  console.log("done");
}
```

the contract can be seen here: https://moonriver.moonscan.io/address/0xFfc7780C34B450d917d557E728f033033CB4fA8C

and the code from which I generated my abi can be found here: https://github.com/mixbytes/lido-dot-ksm/blob/main/contracts/Lido.sol

Comment: `@polkadot/api-contracts` cannot interact with Ethereum-like contracts, only those using the Substrate contracts pallet. In this case it would seem, since you are trying on Moon*, it is an Ethereum-like contract. (To verify, sharing your ABI would be useful)

Comment: Oh that would make sense, I just assumed that since moonriver was built on kusama that the polkadot api would be able to interact with it. Here is the abi I was using: https://pastebin.com/D5GnE8cE. Also if you have any tips for how to interact with this contract using javascript that would be super helpful:)

Comment: For ETH-contracts you can use the normal web3.js/ethers.js toolsets.

Comment: Also, you are saying that you connect to the Moonriver network but the RPC endpoint you are using is `kusama-rpc.polkadot.io`. This Kusama and **not** Moonriver. Parachains have their own endpoint. You do not connect through their relay chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments are correct, `@polkadot/api-contract` can only interact with wasm contracts deployed on chains that include `pallet-contracts`

In your case, you need a JS solution to interact with an Ethereum smart contract on Moonriver, which uses a [different set of pallets](https://docs.moonbeam.network/learn/features/eth-compatibility/#frontier).

The Moonbeam docs have a tutorial on how to configure Hardhat and interact with a deployed contract in the Hardhat console.
https://docs.moonbeam.network/builders/build/eth-api/dev-env/hardhat

Another option you could try is compiling Solidity for Substrate with Solang and using it with `@polkadot/api`
https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/solang#build-for-substrate